# Ant command not recognized as an internal or external command on Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, path, ant

I'm just trying to run `ant` from a Windows terminal. I put my /bin directory under `C:\Program Files\apache-ant\apache-ant-1.10.14`. I added that as my ANT_HOME system variable and added `%ANT_HOME%\bin` to my PATH. I thought maybe it wasn't resolving ANT_HOME but I can cd to ANT_HOME.

[image: echo ANT_HOME]

[image: output of /bin directory]

Comment: It would certainly help to show the output of `Dir "%ANT_HOME%\bin" /A-D` and the actual command you are running which is outputting the message shown in your title. In fact, as you are clearly running the command from a batch file, you should submit, at the very least, a [mcve] of that file's content.

Comment: @Compo updated to include more info. Just trying to run `ant`.

Comment: That is only some of the information I asked for, we need the batch file content, in order to isolate the issue. I could make a couple of guessses, **1.** You have in that script defined a variable named `path`, and in doing so, overwritten the important system variable. **2.** You have a corrupted or modified `pathext` variable, the value of which should always begin with `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH`, and in that order. What is the output from `Set Path`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding adding it manually, that may work. If that doesn't work, try putting it in a folder on your desktop and all the files for the program there. then try 'cd'ing to  that folder then trying again. Then troubleshoot from then on.

Comment: Adding it to the path manually does work, but I want to know why it's not working using ANT_HOME.